# Can a LUKS2 detached header technically be used for multiple drives?

Tags: luks

First, I'm aware that [a similar question has already been answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303813/can-i-use-a-luks-detached-header-for-multiple-drives). The answer was YES, but I'd like a second opinion, because :

- The question didn't specify if it was LUKS1 or LUKS2
- Something I've read on Wikipedia casts a doubt in my mind.

So, the question is : **technically**, can a LUKS2 detached header be used for multiple drives ? I know that it's not recommended from a security point of view (see answer to the previously mentioned post), but here I am only interested in the technical side of the question.

What casts a doubts in my mind is [Wikipedia's statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup#LUKS2) that a LUKS2 header contains, in its JSON area, segments that describe encrypted areas on the disk. Which would mean that a LUKS2 header is tied to a specific drive, and thus can not be re-used for other drives :

> Directly after the binary header comes the JSON area, containing the objects config (configuration), keyslots, digests, segments (describes encrypted areas on the disk), and tokens containing extra metadata.

So, what do you think ? Can a same LUKS2 detached header be used for several drives ? Is there maybe a difference to be made between several identical drives and several radically different drives (e.g., a HDD and a USB stick) ?

Comment: The header probably consists of the "LUKS size". You"ll lose capacity if the size is smaller than the drive size, and it probably won't work at all if it's larger. Also, beware of logical block size (LBS) difference (512 vs 4096). Since the LUKS size should be a logical block count, the (correct) size would differ drastically on drives with different LBS (but even same capacity in bytes).

Comment: So, if I understand you, it's best to create the header first with the largest drive. Let's say I have a 4TB and a 1TB drive, both with 4K sectors. Then the right way to do it would be to first create the header with the 4TB drive, and then that header can be re-used without issue with the 1TB drive. Do I get this right ?

Comment: At second thought, I think your comment is inaccurate. As @frostschutz mentioned (and I just verified on my setup), a LUKS header doesn't contain any information regarding a device's size (it mentions `length: (whole device)`)

Comment: Well, the spec seems to allow the a size of "dynamic" for the "user area", but I can't say for sure what cryptsetup would do. All I know is normally one is expected to resize the LUKS if the underlying partition/drive is planned to be resized. Maybe it is no longer necessary, maybe it still is (i.e., the "special" size "dynamic" is not really used by the implementation). If it is, then no, you should not create it on the 4TB drive, but the 1TB drive (and you can resize it before you use it to unlock/open the 4TB drive).

Comment: I was probably wrong about the logical block size issue though. It seems that LUKS use the unit byte to store the metadata everywhere. Apparently it allows the mapper to have different (smaller or larger) logical block size than the underlying device, and the size probably depends on the encryption sector size, which you can explicitly specify when you format. (See the cryptsetup luks format man page for details / implication.)

Comment: `All I know is normally one is expected to resize the LUKS if the underlying partition/drive is planned to be resized.` : I don't think that this operation (`cryptsetup resize`) will alter the LUKS header. It even seems that `cryptsetup resize` is only needed for online resizing operations (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322905/what-does-cryptsetup-resize-do-if-luks-doesnt-store-partition-size) : `If you don't mind rebooting or remounting, you'll never need cryptsetup resize as it happens automatically offline.`

Comment: IMO, and after reading @frostschutz's answer, I think you can easily re-use an existing header to encrypt a new drive, without paying attention to the drives' sizes. Drive sizes don't matter to LUKS

Comment: Well, TIAS. Indeed I misread `cryptsetup resize` as the way to resize a LUKS but it really is for online resizing the mapper. It does seem that there isn't even a way to set/change the LUKS size. (Still, the *spec* does allow a fixed size in byte.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but it's a bad idea, security wise, to actually use it for independent devices. The answer you linked covers it very well. So I would only recommend it if the data is related, like backup images or snapshots of one and the same LUKS device. Or perhaps in a deployment scenario where a `cryptsetup reencrypt` will be done on first boot to switch the identical header to an independent one.

There may be some side issues that prevent a device from working with a given LUKS2 header:

If your sector size is 4096, the device must be multiple of 4096 bytes large. dm-crypt will refuse to work with a device that has an odd number of 512-byte sectors (you have to use a loop device with sizelimit to discard the last partial 4K-sector yourself). This is rarely an issue since most things are 4K-aligned nowadays (and you can just stick to 512 byte sectors for LUKS).

If you are using advanced features like dm-integrity with LUKS2, the device you open with this header requires initialization. Otherwise it would have all the wrong integrity checksums and be unusable. So a LUKS2+integrity header can only be used with devices that were initialized with this header.

Like you mention, it's also possible for a LUKS2 header to describe specific data segments (offsets, sizes), which would lock it to devices with a specific size. But in practice it's being used for "whole device" encryption only and the size is not even stored in the header.

So in luksDump, it looks like this:

```
Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 4096 [bytes]
```

And you can use any device with it and cryptsetup will encrypt the whole thing for you.

With an external header, the offset can technically be set to 0, though that has its own set of issues - your device will lack UUID/LABEL and random data could be misidentified as another meaningful data.

Comment: So, the TLDR; version of your answer would be : it's technically possible (again, I'm not talking about the security considerations here, only the technical feasibility), provided all drives are 4K aligned, OR provided I still use 512K sectors for LUKS (which is still LUKS' default, at least in the 2.3.7 version I'm currently using). If mixing non-4K drives, it can still be done, albeit with additional caution. And it CAN NOT be done when using dm-integrity.

Comment: yes. for the sector size, there is no default for LUKS2 anymore, it auto-detects either 512 or 4096, this is mentioned in more detail in the manpage (it was changed in cryptsetup 2.4.x). With an external header it's more likely to pick 4096

Comment: Note that "4K-aligned" does not imply that the the total size is a multiple of 4096 bytes.